# Sci-fi trilogy with a female fighter pilot who falls in love with enemy commander with psi powers

Tags: story-identification, christian, allegory

About twenty years ago, maybe longer, I read a sci-fi trilogy. Can't remember much about it, but I remember enjoying it. It was a Christian allegory, I believe. At least I think that's the right word.

Anyway, there is this female fighter pilot who belongs to a bunch of religious zealots. During a raid, she is captured instead of dying a glorious death like she was ordered to.

So, the commander who captured her has some sort of genetically engineered psi powers and there is also a prophecy about a child of his line with superior mind powers that was supposed to end the war or something.

Anyway, the female pilot is deprogrammed and falls in love with her captor. Meanwhile, there are people after them who do not want their children to be born, so they flee to another planet while they plan a mission that should defeat those who want them dead.

Sorry. That's all I can remember other than the possibility that the titles of the books were each a single word. Does any of this ring a bell?

Comment: An allegory is essentially a story with a hidden deeper meaning. Do you feel that fits what you're aiming for?

Comment: Pretty much. It was definitely a story about a prophecy and a 'savior', with a sci-fi theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Firebird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_(Tyers_novel))* by Kathy Tyers. If you read it as a trilogy, the odds are that you read [the second edition](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/192266.Firebird_Trilogy), which seems to have a slightly different summary in Wikipedia than the first edition:

[image: Book Cover - Firebird]

> Firebird is a military pilot assigned to a risky venture to capture a Federate world outpost. Because she is a wastling, she is considered expendable. Leading her tagwing fighter group, she is captured by Federate colonel Brennen Caldwell, a telepath who senses something special about her. She attempts honorable suicide by poison for her failure, but Caldwell thwarts her medically. Under duress, her military knowledge is used by Caldwell to save the Federate outpost. Firebird begins to see the dishonorable tactics of her people for what they are.
>
> Caldwell, in addition to being the most powerful Ehretan telepath of his generation, is also heir to religious prophecies among his people, and the most senior telepath in a government that mistrusts them for their abilities. Caldwell is promoted to general for his victory in the Veroh battle, as well as his diplomacy with the captured Firebird. In her, he sensed a strong possibility of connaturality, a deep personality congruity that is essential for telepaths to be married. As he has strong convictions against marrying outside his faith, and being barred from proselytizing, much of the book revolves around Caldwell trying to bridge the gap to Firebird by demonstrating the goodness of his spirit to her, offering life and hope to one who believed herself as good as dead.
>
> Following Netaia's failure on Veroh, Firebird's sister Carradee ascends the throne after their mother commits suicide, a tradition within the royal family. She favors a conciliatory posture with the Federacy. Their other sister, Phoena, secretly plots the overthrow of Federate occupation along with members of the nobility, by secretly building an ecological weapon of great power. After several political and military dangers are overcome by Caldwell and Firebird, they ignore his orders and carry out a special ops mission to destroy Phoena's research lab. During the climactic battle, when Caldwell has been incapacitated and his telepathic powers are not available, Firebird casts her faith to the Great Speaker who sang the universe into existence, and strengthened by this, overcomes great odds to successfully neutralize the weapon.
>
> The religious differences thus settled, the story ends with Caldwell proposing pair bonding (marriage) to Firebird.

Wikipedia also notes that the rewrite was also where it moved from Science Fiction Romance to a Christian Allegory.

My eventually successful search terms were *science fiction trilogy captured pilot prophecy*

Comment: THAT'S IT!! THANK YOU. This has been bugging me for weeks.